# What is a better option to use instead of jQuery’s .is(‘:hover’) to show a div when hovering over another div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

What is another or better option to use instead of jQuery’s .is(‘:hover’) to show a div when hovering over another div.

I have a global nav with a search icon (li#search-open) at the far right, last item. when mousing over (hovering) i want a div containing the search form (#search-container) located directly beneath the global nav to none to slide down.

http://thetownie.com/nav/index.html

I have not gotten satisfactory results. So far mainly relying on jQuery’s .is(‘:hover’) function and also using a window.setInterval function to continually check if user is hovering over either the #search-open or the #search-container. It is working intermittently.

What is a better way to do this? Can this be done w/ CSS only?

note the CNN global nav does the same as what i am trying to achieve here. for example try mousing over ‘US’, ‘World’ or ‘Politics’

www.cnn.com

any help would be so appreciated. my code is below

```
<nav>
 <div id="main-nav-wrapper">
  <div id="main-nav-inner-wrapper">
   <ul id="six-items">
    <li class="a"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="a"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="a"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li id="search-open"><a href="#" class="flaticon-magnifier13"></a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="search-container" class="closed">
 <form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter search terms here...." id="search-input"/>
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
 </form>
 </div>         
 </div><!-- end nav inner wrapper -->
 </div></div></nav>
```

my sorry js is here,....

```
var searchcontainerhover = false;
var searchopenhover ;

function slideSearchUp(){
  jQuery('#search-container').slideUp('fast');  
 }

 function testIfHover(){
  if(jQuery('#search-container').is(':hover')) {
 searchcontainerhover = true;
 } else {
 searchcontainerhover = false;
}

if(jQuery('#search-open').is(':hover')) {
 searchopenhover = true;
} else {
 searchopenhover = false;
}

console.log(searchcontainerhover);
console.log(searchopenhover);

if((searchcontainerhover == false) && (searchopenhover == false)) {
setTimeout(slideSearchUp, 3000); 
 } 
}  
window.setInterval(testIfHover, 1000);

jQuery('#search-open').mouseenter(
  function(){
   jQuery('#search-container').slideDown('fast');
   jQuery( "#search-container").removeClass( "closed" ).addClass( "open" );
 searchopen = true;
 console.log(searchopen);
});
```

Comment: why not just using jquery handler?

Comment: Ah, i see. You're trying to hide it automatically after a period of time, if the user isn't still hovering over it. What you need is a mouseleave handler with a setTimeout that gets cleared by a new mouseenter handler on search-container.

Comment: $('#YourselectorDiv').hover(function(){$('#Divtoshow').show();});

Comment: You can just nest the search container inside of the li and use pure CSS to show and hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this by adding a mouseleave handler to both the button and the search container as well as a mouseenter on the search container.

```
function slideSearchUp(){
  jQuery('#search-container').slideUp('fast');  
}
var searchContainerTimeout;

jQuery('#search-open').mouseenter(function(){
   jQuery('#search-container').slideDown('fast');
   jQuery( "#search-container").removeClass( "closed" ).addClass( "open" );
});
jQuery('#search-open,#search-container').mouseleave(function(){
   searchContainerTimeout = setTimeout(slideSearchUp,3000);
})
$('#search-container').mouseenter(function(){
   clearTimeout(searchContainerTimeout);
   searchContainerTimeout = setTimeout(slideSearchUp,3000);
});
```

Now what will happen is when the mouse enters **search-open**, **search-container** will slide open. When the mouse leaves **search-open**, a timeout will start that will close **search-container** after three seconds. If the mouse the enters **search-container** or re-enters **search-open**, the timeout will be stopped. If the mouse leaves search-container, it will be started again.

Comment: both answers are good! i think that 2nd one has an error. the last line ,,,   searchContainerTimeout = setTimeout(.....    should not be there.

Comment: i'm going to go with door number two. it works best in the context i'm currently in. am in Drupal and it's an issue to add new class to all form element.

Answer (score 1):

this Demo might helpfull to you, you extend this with animations etc.

```js
  
  
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#search").mouseenter(function(){

   $("#searchdiv").show();
   $(document).bind("mousemove", mousemove);

  });

  function mousemove(e){
    
   if(!$(e.target).hasClass("search")){
    $(document).unbind("mousemove", mousemove);
    $("#searchdiv").hide();
   }  
  }
  
 });
```

```css
span{      
  border: 1px solid blue;
}


.search{
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#searchdiv{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>One</span><span>Two</span><span>Three</span><span>Four</span><span id="search" class="right search">Search</span>

<div id="searchdiv" class="search">Search Div</div>
```

Comment: i had to add class="search" to all form elements or it wouldn't work reliably. also had to remove the anchor tag in the search open LI.